# Why torch.autograd.grad() returns None with torch.cat?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I know the `torch.autograd.grad()` returns None if the gradient is stopped somehow, however, I am wondering what is wrong with the following snippet?

```
x = torch.rand(6, requires_grad=True)

y = x.pow(2).sum()
z = torch.cat([x])

grad1 = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, allow_unused=True)
grad2 = torch.autograd.grad(y, z, allow_unused=True)
      
print(f'grad1 = {grad1}, grad = {grad2}')
```

The output is `grad1 = (tensor([0.3705, 0.7468, 0.6102, 1.8640, 0.3518, 0.5397]),), grad = (None,)`.
I am expecting the `grad2` is the same to `grad1`, because `z` is essentially the `x`. May I know why please?

---

Update: After reading the [post](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html) and the help from @Ivan, I conclude the reason is `x` is a leaf node of `y` but `z` is not any more. `x` is the leaf node of both `y` and `z` in the computation graph, but there is no direct path from `z` to `y`, so the `torch.autograd.grad` returns None.

Note: The returned value `None` does not necessarily guarantee the values are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensor `z` was not used to compute the value of `y`, as such it is not connected to its computation graph, and you won't get a gradient on `z`, since it's not *connected* to `y`.

On the other hand, the following will work:

```
>>> y = x.pow(2).sum()
>>> torch.autograd.grad(y, x, allow_unused=True)
(tensor([0.3134, 1.6802, 0.1989, 0.8495, 1.9203, 1.0905]),)

>>> z = torch.cat([x])
>>> y = z.pow(2).sum()
>>> torch.autograd.grad(y, z, allow_unused=True)
(tensor([0.3134, 1.6802, 0.1989, 0.8495, 1.9203, 1.0905]),)
```

Comment: 1. Can I take return value None as 0 values? 2. Why does it not return 0 values instead?

Comment: `None` means there was no gradient computed for that value, while `0` means the gradient's value equals `0`. Which are two substantially different things.

Comment: No gradient computed means the change of `x` does not affect `y`. Therefore, they are different from the implementation's perspective but from the mathematically perspective, `None` leads to `0`, not the other way around. Am I right?

Comment: BTW, what if the real case of `[x]` is `model.parameters()`? We can't compute the `y` from `z` again. What shall do we then?

Comment: *"what if the real case of `[x]` is `model.parameters()`"*, what do you mean by that? Are you looking to compute the gradient of the norm of your parameters?

Comment: Actually, I would like to compute the Hessian of loss w.r.t my model's parameter. Moreover, I would like to compute the jacobian matrix of outputs w.r.t my model's parameter.

Comment: You can do so  using [`torch.autograd.functional.hessian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.hessian.html) and [`torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html) respectively.